# Странное поведение php array_unique

Tags: php

```
$arr = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 50000; $i++) {
    $arr[$i] = rand(1, 100000);
}

echo"Элементов в исходном массиве:";
print_r(count($arr));

//массив уникальных элементов
$arrOfUnic = array_unique($arr);

echo"Элементов в массиве после удаления дублей:";
print_r(count($arrOfUnic));

echo"случайный элемент:";
$randomIndex = array_rand($arrOfUnic);
print_r($randomIndex);
echo"=>";
print_r($arrOfUnic[$randomIndex]);
```

Всегда один и тот же результат:
Элементов в исходном массиве:
50000
Элементов в массиве после удаления дублей:
32768
случайный элемент:
15535=>79545.
Если массив

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 17000; $i++) {
$arr[$i] = rand(1, 25000);
}
```

По кругу выдается 3 результата:

Элементов в массиве после удаления дублей:
14917
случайный элемент:
2118=>23979

Элементов в массиве после удаления дублей:
14943
случайный элемент:
13481=>23870

Элементов в массиве после удаления дублей:
14878
случайный элемент:
268=>12020

Comment: Ну вот вы и встретились с генератором псевдослучайных чисел

Comment: Благодарю! Навели на mt_rand - стало получше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По своему опыту скажу что функция `rand` генерирует числа ужасно, и с этим ничего не делалось, только в версии 7.1 её уже убрали и оставили как алиас на функцию `mt_rand`.

Если вы используете версию PHP ниже 7.1, то рекомендую как раз использовать именно функцию `mt_rand`, дублей должно быть меньше, потому что используется алгоритм: `Mersenne Twister Random Number Generator`. К тому же ходили слухи что она в разы быстрее чем `rand` (хотя на самом деле прирост скорости не особо заметен).

UPD. Как альтернативу `array_rand` могу посоветовать вот такой код, говорят что даже он быстрее и лучше:

```
$a = ['http://php.net/', 'http://google.com/', 'http://bbc.co.uk/'];
$website = $a[mt_rand(0, count($a) - 1)];
```

[Источник](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php#112227)

Comment: Спасибо! С mt_rand Лучше.array_rand Еще вопросы вызывает...

Comment: @Dimas забудьте про него и всё, с версии 7.1 как я говорил его вообще убрали, так что смысла нет думать о нём.

Comment: Я про array_rand - ей замены то нет...

Comment: @Dimas обновил ответ

Comment: Yaroslav, спасибо огромное!